# Assert that an event does not fire in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm using `react-testing-library` and trying to assert that an html element is draggable under some circumstance, but not in others. For the happy case I'm using `fireEvent` to fire the drag events but, for the scenarios where dragging should not happen, `fireEvent.drop` throws an exception:

```
Error: Uncaught [Invariant Violation: Cannot call hover while not dragging.]
```

Since the motto for react-testing-library is sort of "test like a user", how can I test that the drag event won't happen without falling into the "test implementation details" trap?

Comment: Did you check if you can use `tothrow`? https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror

Comment: Show the code, create minimal, reproducible example

Comment: @moy2010, any proper fix on this?

Comment: @SurajBande, sorry. I just checked and I haven't fixed this issue yet.

Comment: Thanks, can you please give a try with my solution added below?

Answer (score -1):

I have added setTimeout and it worked for me.

```
setTimeout(
FireEvent.drop(dest)
)
```

But not sure how it will work in your case. Just give a try and hope it won't break or create a latency in your process.